# Sqlite3 error message is shown on Postgresql application

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sqlite, express

I am learning to build an app using node express and knexjs to connect to the Postgresql database. When I do a post request, this warning message shows up. The data that I try to post is not in the database. Maybe the app thought I am using sqlite3?

> sqlite does not support inserting default values. Set the `useNullAsDefault` flag to hide this warning. (see docs http://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert).

This is my server.js.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const knex = require('knex');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

const database = knex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'xxxxxxx',
    password : 'xxxxxxx',
    database : 'xxxxxxxxdb'
  }
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public/'));

app.get('/add_athlete', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('add_athlete.html', {root: path.resolve(__dirname + '/../public/templates')});
});

app.post('/add_athlete', function(req, res) {
  knex('participants').insert({
    participant_number: 1,
    email: "test@gmail.com",
    first_name: "test",
    last_name: "again"
  })
  .then (function () {
    res.json({success: true, message: "ok"})
  })
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Running at port 3000');
```

Comment: Have you tried using `database(‘participants’).insert` instead of `knex(‘participants...`? (Sorry, on the phone with auto format on... use regular single quotes of course)

Comment: lol, it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: Awesome :) Maybe the docs are wrong in that point, because they also use `knex('participants...`

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, this question has an answer.

As mentioned in the comments, you probably want to use the created database instance.

So instead of `knex('participants').insert...` you probably want to use `database('participants').insert...`